# How to read JSON data into an HTML Select Element in a Meteor app?

Tags: json, meteor, html-select, spacebars, meteor-helper

I want to load some "lookup table"-type stuff, which I've stored in a file named "settings.json" in my Meteor app. The json is:

```
[{
    "uccampus": [
      "UC Santa Cruz",
      "UC Berkeley",
      "UC Davis",
      "UC Irvine",
      "UC Los Angeles",
      "UC Merced",
      "UC Riverside",
      "UC San Diego",
      "UC San Francisco",
      "UC Santa Barbara"
    ]
}]
```

I want to load this data into a template named "tblTravelerInfo2", so I've got this code in the .js file:

```
Template.tblTravelerInfo2.helpers({
  uccampuses: function(){
    return Meteor.settings.uccampuses;
  }
});
```

...and this in the corresponding template in the html file:

```
<select name="selectcampus" id="selectcampus" title="Please select a campus">
    {{#each uccampus}}
      <option>{{what}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

As you might be able to suss out, I don't know what should go where I put "{{what}}" as a placeholder. What should it be?

### UPDATE

It's still not working. This is now my json:

```
[{
    "uccampus": [
    {name:"UC Santa Cruz"},
    {name:"UC Berkeley"},
    {name:"UC Davis"},
    {name:"UC Irvine"},
    {name:"UC Los Angeles"},
    {name:"UC Merced"},
    {name:"UC Riverside"},
    {name:"UC San Diego"},
    {name:"UC San Francisco"},
    {name:"UC Santa Barbara"}
    ]
}]
```

...and this is the helper:

```
  Template.tblTravelerInfo2.helpers({
    uccampuses: function(){
      return Meteor.settings.uccampuses[0];
    }
  });
```

I've also tried:

```
  Template.tblTravelerInfo2.helpers({
    uccampuses: function(){
      return Meteor.settings.uccampus[0];
    }
  });
```

...and this is the HTML:

```
{{#each uccampus}}
    <option>{{name}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

I also tried this as the HTML:

```
{{#each uccampuses}}
    <option>{{uccampus.name}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

...but in both cases the Select Options are not populated. No err msg, but no population, either.

### UPDATE 2

I started the app with "meteor --settings settings.json" and got this in the console:

C:\Meteor\scheduler>meteor --settings settings.json
[[[[[ C:\Meteor\scheduler ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors prevented startup:

While preparing to run:
   settings.json: parse error reading settings file

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

Here is the settings file in its entirety:

"public" : {
    "uccampus": [
    {"name":"UC Santa Cruz"},
    {"name":"UC Berkeley"},
    {"name":"UC Davis"},
    {"name":"UC Irvine"},
    {"name":"UC Los Angeles"},
    {"name":"UC Merced"},
    {"name":"UC Riverside"},
    {"name":"UC San Diego"},
    {"name":"UC San Francisco"},
    {"name":"UC Santa Barbara"}
    ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are accessing Meteor.settings on the client you need to include your data in a public key as follows:

settings.json

```
"public" : {
    "uccampus": [
    {"name":"UC Santa Cruz"},
    {"name":"UC Berkeley"},
    {"name":"UC Davis"},
    {"name":"UC Irvine"},
    {"name":"UC Los Angeles"},
    {"name":"UC Merced"},
    {"name":"UC Riverside"},
    {"name":"UC San Diego"},
    {"name":"UC San Francisco"},
    {"name":"UC Santa Barbara"}
    ]
}
```

In your helper call on this public settings like this:

```
  uccampus: function(){
    return Meteor.settings.public.uccampus;
  }
```

Finally in spacebars call the data like this:

```
{{#each uccampus}}
    <option>{{name}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I clicked too soon; I was sure that was going to work, but it doesn't (or I'm doing something wrong); please see my Update above.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Sorry I forgot a critical part of calling settings in to the client. I've updated my answer to reflect your new data set. This should work now.

Comment: It seems like it should work, but it still doesn't. I've got that exact code in each place: json, .js, and .html

Comment: Can you try this in a browser console to make sure your settings are in the public key? --  console.log(Meteor.settings.public);  . It should return an object with your uccampus array inside of it.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Please also make sure settings.json is at the root of your application and that you are starting meteor as follows: meteor --settings settings.json

Comment: In Chrome Dev Tools' console, after entering that, I got, "console.log(Meteor.settings.public);
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'public' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:2:28
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
"

Comment: settings.json is directly beneath my project folder, but I start my app with simply "meteor" while in its folder. Please see Update 2.

Comment: Your settings file is not being loaded if you can't see an object when you run Meteor.settings in the browser console. You need to use the --settings flag in your startup command to point to your settings.json file. See here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settings

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, and it errored out. For a deployed app, would that cause an issue, or do you somehow provide the settings flag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88725/discussion-between-gdatadan-and-b-clay-shannon).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

template.js:

```
Template.tblTravelerInfo2.helpers({
 uccampuses: function(){
   return Meteor.settings.uccampuses;
 }
});
```

template.html:

```
{{#each uccampuses}}
 <option>{{.}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Aisle Tri it. It's it. This minimum character requirement for comments is kind of walking-challenged.

Comment: I did a typo there, put 'uccampus' instead of 'uccampuses'.

Comment: Are you certain that `Meteor.settings.uccampuses` isn't empty at the moment `uccampuses` helper are called?